# Mergeing Excel Workbooks into Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm currently trying to merge 24 workbooks into one workbook with 24 sheets. Workbooks are named run 1 to run 24 and I am trying to merge into a template which already has 2 sheets named summary and pressure. I'm very new to coding for this and any copied code from other questions doesn't seem to work for me. I attempted the record macros where I moved into the template but when trying to apply this it comes up with a run time error 9. The coding looks like this.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Current Template.xlsx").Sheets(2)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Workbooks("Current Template.xlsx").Sheets(3)
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to help you:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("target.xlsm")  'Considering that macro is placed in your target file
    i = 1
    While i < 25
        Workbooks.Open ("run" & i & ".xlsx")   'give path as applicable
        Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("run" & i & ".xlsx")
        With wb1
            .Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)   'the new sheet will be placed after the last sheet in target file
            .Close
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I changed target.xlsm to template.xlsm as this is the target workbook. But it Says there is a run-time error 1004 and to check the file spelling and location are correct. I am not sure how to enter the path. Is there a specific coding line for this?

Comment: Path is your folder location. e.g. C:\rusk\run. Also mention on which line you are getting this error.